# Pushing promises in an array the array remains null

Tags: node.js, promise, promise.all

I am pushing the promises in promises =[] array but when passing the promises in promises. All the array remains null which resolves and send null result if my code has any issue please answer

```
searchProductVariant: (start, end, combinations) => {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
{
  var promises = [];
  console.log(start, "  ", end);
  for (let i = start; i < start + end; i++) {
    vv = combinations[i - start].product_variant_name.split("_");
    console.log("kk", vv);

    vv.forEach((v) => {
      sql = `SELECT id FROM ecommerce.variant_values as varval where varval.value like '${v}'`;
      pool.query(sql, [], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log("the errrror is", error);
        }
        if (results[0].id) {
          console.log("i is ", i);
          let temp = addProductVariantDetails(i, results[0].id);
          promises.push(temp
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
  console.log(promises); //it prints null
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then((resul) => {
      return resolve(resul);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return reject(err);
    });
})
}
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Also, this doesn't look like the full code. Please post a [mre].

Comment: this is the complete code the addProductVariantDetails functions returns a promise return a promise

Comment: Where is this function called? What are the possible inputs? What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is the message from the database when rows are added successfully in the database or the error message if there is some error. the addProductVariantDetails in saving the variant detail in the database and returns a promise it. this function is calling multiple times and thus pushing it into an array. passing that array in promise.all should wait until all promises resolves and pass the result

Comment: There's some obvious problems with this code, but have you considered looked for a promise/async/await-enabled client for your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pool.query` receives a callback, and that's the only thing that adds to the `promises` array. I think it's likely that you're just trying to run `Promise.all` before any of the `query` callbacks return. You might need to switch to a Promise-based version of `pool.query`, if one exists, or you can write your own like this.

```js
searchProductVariant: (start, end, combinations) => {
  // DELETE: Original Promise wrapper. Return Promise.all result directly.
  var queries = [];  // NEW: Track queries.
  var promises = [];
  console.log(start, "  ", end);
  for (let i = start; i < start + end; i++) {
    vv = combinations[i - start].product_variant_name.split("_");
    console.log("kk", vv);

    vv.forEach((v) => {
      sql = `SELECT id FROM ecommerce.variant_values as varval where varval.value like '${v}'`;
      // NEW: Wrap pool.query to create a promise that waits for the possible add
      // to the promises array, adding the separate promises array.
      queries.push(
        new Promise((resolve, _) => {
          pool.query(sql, [], (error, results, fields) => {
            resolve([error, results, fields]);
          })
        }).then([error, results, fields] => {
          if (error) {
            console.log("the error is", error);
          }
          if (results[0].id) {
            console.log("i is ", i);
            let temp = addProductVariantDetails(i, results[0].id);
            // Keep temp in an array so we only return valid results,
            // but also return it so the returned Promise surfaces
            // any rejection issued at any time.
            promises.push(temp);
            return temp;
          }
        }));
    });
  }
  console.log(promises);
  // Wait for the queries, then wait for the promise results.
  return Promise.all(queries).then(() => Promise.all(promises));
}
```

You could also simplify this code by dropping the `promises` array entirely and simply returning `Promise.all(queries)` at the end; however, you'd need to filter out the `undefined` results that come from any `queries` promises that result in errors or ID-less results, and I don't know enough about your code to know whether `undefined` can be properly filtered. (You also don't check that `results.length > 0`, but as you have it that would result in a Promise rejection either way.)

Comment: "*You could also simplify this code by replacing the `promises.push(temp)` with `return temp`*" - that's not just a simplification, it's actually a correction. The code as written currently will cause an *unhandled promise rejection* error (which can crash the process), if one of the `temp` promises returned by `addProductVariantDetails` do reject before all the `queries` are fulfilled. (And also if any of the queries rejects). Please fix that as you suggested.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, I'd written that bit about resolving before removing the outer promise constructor, but forgot to remove the description. That said, I don't see where the unhandled promise rejection would come from other than if `pool.query` itself throws synchronously. If `addProductVariantDetails` either rejects or throws it will manifest as the overall return value rejecting, so nothing is unhandled.

Comment: The problem is that the rejection only manifests as the overall return value once the second `Promise.all` has run - which happens only once all queries fulfill. If any of the `temp` promises rejects before that, it has no `.then()` handlers set up yet, and will be causing an unhandled rejection error.

Comment: @Bergi Here, if it'll make you happy, I'll `return temp` but also keep the pushed `promises` since the OP hasn't told us whether `undefined` is a valid promise resolution value. It's a little less efficient to duplicate `queries` and `promises`, but only a tiny bit, and keeps my code from functionally diverging from the OP's.